# Need Help Finding Out the ID / Identifier for Banner Block So I Can Edit Them In CMS Block

Tags: theme, cms-block

**Website is:** `www.HighCaliberLine.com`

**Theme is:** `Ultimo`

There are 3 banner blocks on the website that I'm trying to edit through CMS block. The problem is I can't find the ID Block / Identifier for these.

Can anyone help me find the ID Block / Identifier on these and also explain where I can find these ID Block / Identifier?

**Please see image for further details**

[image]
Thanks

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.. Can you please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, after hours and help from Sharif. The location of this edit was in CMS -> Pages -> Home Page (this was named something else, reason why I couldn't find it)

Thanks Sharif for your time and options!

Answer (score 1):

If these CMS blocks positions were defined in theme by default I believe that Theme Developer will help you more if you will request support from them here http://themeforest.net/item/ultimo-fluid-responsive-magento-theme/3231798/support

Or you can try to filter CMS blocks by keyword "banner" in CMS -> Static Blocks - Identifier field.

Comment: Sadly I'm working off a previous person who did edit to this theme, so I don't have the info to login onto themeforest.

Comment: Do you have many static blocks in CMS? I think you can spend some time and check code in static blocks and find relevant html code.

Comment: The previous person working on this ID these three banner as Home-Top-Banner-1, Home-Top-Banner-2, Home-Top-Banner-3 on the CMS page. But when i tried doing edit on these and saving (also refreshing cache) it didn't do anything to the frontend. I been looking through the XHTML to see what the actually ID but no luck.

Comment: What is in homepage html code? Maybe they are defined there? Did you check widgets? They could be inserted via widgets too.

Comment: I did check the widgets and it say Home Top Banner but I applied that as a ID Block and no luck. What is the homepage XHTML called so I can locate it?

Comment: The standard homepage html should be in CMS -> Pages with URL key home. Also are you aware of website Scope? You could change a lot of settings (or content), but for the wrong website or Store view.

Comment: There no homepage html in the cms page. Yeah so far the content is selected under the correct website / store view.

Comment: Can you enable Template Path Hints and paste screenshot here?

Comment: I tried to turn on Template Path Hints but nothing show up on the frontend. I did the following: http://insync.co.in/how-to-enable-template-path-and-block-name-hints-in-magento-commerce/

Comment: Check carefully with Website Scope and with Allowed IPs Field.

Comment: Check carefully with Website Scope and with Allowed IPs Field.  <- I'm not sure what you mean by this or how to do this.

Comment: I mean the scope of Template Path Hints dropdown is 'Store View' make sure that is is switched to Yes in correct Scope. Also Template Path Hints will be shown only for IP addresses that are entered in 'Allowed IP' field, which also has 'Store View' scope. https://yadi.sk/i/Z0QERUIeg7jcs

Comment: Here what i see. For some reason it didn't show any info regarding those banner from what I see. here the image: http://postimg.org/image/v9w0axohp/

Comment: You can search for content of this blocks by running query in DB and looking for jpg image file. 

If you have access to DB you can run this MySQL query in 'cms_block' table

'SELECT * 
FROM  `cms_block` 
WHERE  `content` LIKE  'banner_Footer_355x159_safety.jpg''

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to MySQL. is there another way?

Comment: What is in local.xml? maybe that guy just inserted html on homepage with '<action method="setText">' ? Did you checked xml?

Comment: i'm looking at the local.xml. Not sure what i'm looking for.

Comment: http://we.tl/o61w85a5UI             here the local.xml

Comment: Did you checked content of Static Blocks listed on lines 1457 - 1461 in local.xml ? There is 
'block_id' 
named 
'block_home_preface'

Comment: Damn that not it too. it just created another banner on top of the original one. See jpeg

Comment: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=28l5j0m&s=8#.VTVVMJMy748